# Generating an HTML link to a file once it is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bit of code which pops open a jquery mobile dialog box and updates the contents of the dialog box with a link to a file when it detects the file exists on the server. It checks for the existence of the file every second and tries up to 10 times.

The code works fine, however, when the user clicks on the actual link in the dialog box to download the file, nothing happens. However, if the browser is refreshed, the file does get downloaded. Obviously, I'd like the user to just click once on the link to begin the download.

I'm sure the way I'm using `setTimeout()` is what's gumming things up but I'm not sure what else to try. Javascript/jquery is not my strong suit. Thanks!

```
function download_notify(grp_name, token) {
  $('#download_dialog_open_button').click();
  exists(0);
  function exists (try_count) {
    try_count = try_count + 1;
    $.ajax ( {
      type: 'HEAD',
      url: '/files/' + grp_name + '_' + token + '.csv',
      async: true,
      error: function (try_count) { 
        if (try_count < 10) 
          {setTimeout(exists, 1000);
        } else { 
          return; 
        }
      }, 
      success: function () {
        $('#download_dialog h1.ui-title').html('File ready');
        $('#download_dialog .ui-content div').html('<a href="/files/' + grp_name + '_' + token + '.csv">Download</a>');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `\$` instead of  `$` ?

Comment: I was generating it with perl code and had to escape them. Fixed.

Comment: `setTimeout(exists(), 1000);` is wrong. It should be `setTimeout(exists, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. My perl habits leaking into the code there. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `rel="external"` ?, i.e.:

```
$('#download_dialog .ui-content div').html('<a rel="external" href="/files/' + grp_name + '_' + token + '.csv">Download</a>');
```

Comment: That worked! However, I still have a suspicion I'm not using the setTimeout properly.